# Pass <input> value as Ember component invoking param

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I'm quite new to EmberJS and trying to get the component invoked with a param which is dynamicly set via user's input:

```
<input type=date>
{{super-calendar startDate='/* value from the input */'}}
```

Do you have an idea what is the proper way to do it in Ember?

Answer (score 0):

`someVariable`can be property or computed property of controller

```
<input type=date value=someVariable>
{{super-calendar startDate=someVariable}}
```